# Window function after aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm making a report, which includes window function.
I have to sum values by row and show total by manufacturer, but I get different sums:

```
select manufacturer, 
  product_code,
  date_code,
  sum(packs),
  sum(packs) over(partition by manufacturer,date_code)
from staging.sales
group by manufacturer, 
  product_code,
  date_code, 
  packs
```

I assume, it's due to grouping packs, but without it I get error. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add the error you're receiving to your question? Consider our viewpoint - the more relevant information, the better we can help you.

Comment: You get "Different Sums" when? You didn't say what two things you do to get different sums and from which column(s) you are seeing different sums.

Comment: Remove packs from `GROUP BY` Clause.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum(sum(packs))`:

```
select manufacturer, product_code, date_code,
       sum(packs),
       sum(sum(packs)) over (partition by manufacturer) as manufacturer_sum
from staging.sales
group by manufacturer, product_code, date_code;
```

However, if you just need the total by manufacturer, perhaps you don't need window functions at all

```
select manufacturer, sum(packs) as manufacturer_sum
from staging.sales
group by manufacturer;
```

Comment: I may have described it inaccurate, but sales are by day, I need to aggregate it to month and show manufacturer monthly total by all products in next column.

Comment: That is exactly what the first query does.